# Rounding to a specific number of significant digits in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a rounding function oracle to round to a specific number of significant digits?

For example, round 1278 to 1300, round to two significant digits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select round(1348,-2) from dual;
```

Comment: That works for his one example, but not in general.  For example, `select round(.1348,-2) from dual;` returns 0, but he probably wants 0.13.

Comment: Now thats a much more interesting question. Found some relevant discussion here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=295697&messageID=2848061

Comment: Note the use of 'significant digits' in the question. ROUND works on decimal places instead.

Answer (score 4):

Try `ROUND(x, d - FLOOR(LOG(10, x)) - 1)` where `d` is the number of significant digits and `x` is the value to be rounded.

Example:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(x, d - FLOOR(LOG(10, x)) - 1) 
FROM (SELECT 1278 x, 2 d FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
      SELECT 0.1234 x, 2 d FROM DUAL  );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `3.00` to two or three sig figs.

Comment: @alaybourn It works perfectly [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HwyprwD4). There is a difference between **rounding** a value to a number of significant figures and **displaying** a number of significant figures. `3` is already accurate to 3.s.f. so as a value it does not matter whether you have `3.00` or `3` as they are identical values; if you want to display all the significant figures then you want `3.00` and that is a very different problem to just rounding to 3s.f..

Answer (score 3):

Just off the top of my head, probably a subject to further optimization :)

```
16:54:16 SYSTEM@dwal> select to_number(to_char(1278, '9.9EEEE'))  t from dual;

         T
----------
      1300

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
16:54:34 SYSTEM@dwal> select to_number(to_char(.1234, '9.9EEEE'))  t from dual;

         T
----------
       .12

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Comment: Great answer. And I can use a parameter to determine the number of significant digits like this: `to_number(to_char(p_number, '9.' || lpad('9',p_digits,'9') || 'EEEE'))`

Answer (score 0):

Or just: to_number(to_char(<your_number>,'0.0EEEE'),'0.0EEEE')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to round a number to a number of significant figures then use [@Jeffery Kemp's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709728/rounding-to-a-specific-number-of-significant-digits-in-oracle/75766627#comment121487633_13719406) (except you need to subtract 1 from the digits)

```sql
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(value, '9.' || LPAD('9',digits - 1,'9') || 'EEEE'))
```

or [@f3lix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19814309/1509264) can be fixed to work for `0` and negative numbers using:

```sql
ROUND(value, digits - CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE FLOOR(LOG(10, ABS(value))) + 1 END)
```

If you want to format the number to show a number of significant digits then you can take the rounded number and use `TO_CHAR` to format it and calculate how many digits should be in the integer- and decimal-parts of the format mask:

```sql
SELECT value,
       digits,
       ROUND(value, digits - CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE FLOOR(LOG(10, ABS(value))) + 1 END)
         AS rounded_value,
       TO_CHAR(
         ROUND(value, digits - CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE FLOOR(LOG(10, ABS(value))) + 1 END),
         'FM9'
         || LPAD('0', GREATEST(CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE FLOOR(LOG(10, ABS(value))) + 1 END, 1), '0')
         || CASE
            WHEN digits > CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE FLOOR(LOG(10, ABS(value))) + 1 END
            THEN '.' || LPAD('0', digits - CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE FLOOR(LOG(10, ABS(value))) + 1 END, '0')
            END
       ) AS formatted_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value, digits) AS
  SELECT 1278,       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1234.56789, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1234.56789, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1234.56789, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1234.56789, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1000,       2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1000,       5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 0.1234,     2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 0.1234,     8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3,          2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3.12345,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 0,          2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT -3.12345,   2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT -1.2345e-5, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 99.997,     2 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | DIGITS | ROUNDED_VALUE | FORMATTED_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1278 | 2 | 1300 | 1300 |
| 1234.56789 | 2 | 1200 | 1200 |
| 1234.56789 | 4 | 1235 | 1235 |
| 1234.56789 | 5 | 1234.6 | 1234.6 |
| 1234.56789 | 6 | 1234.57 | 1234.57 |
| 1000 | 2 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 1000 | 5 | 1000 | 1000.0 |
| .1234 | 2 | .12 | 0.12 |
| .1234 | 8 | .1234 | 0.12340000 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 3.0 |
| 3.12345 | 2 | 3.1 | 3.1 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 0.0 |
| -3.12345 | 2 | -3.1 | -3.1 |
| -.000012345 | 3 | -.0000123 | -0.0000123 |
| 99.997 | 2 | 100 | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/djtXUmB5)

Comment: unfortunately this fails when you try to round smth like 99.9997 to 2 figures