# Oracle how to truncate a decimal to 1 significant digit?

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers, rounding

I would like to round decimal numbers down to the first significant digit.
Since they will all have a varying number of leading zero decimals, i searched this site and found the following expression.

```
TRUNC(EPSILON,LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(EPSILON,'.0*')))
```

It works for all numbers that have less than 5 leading 0 decimal places, and does not return the right result when the number has 5 or more leading decimal places.

Edit: Epsilon is a calculated value from a query, the the data type of the values used in the calculation are **Number**.

See below for examples:

```
**EPSILON**     **Expected Result**     **Actual Result**
0.0000083333    0.000008                0
0.0000047666    0.000004                0
0.000025        0.00002                 0.00002
0.000012195     0.00001                 0.00001
0.00002         0.00002                 0.00002
0.00036333334   0.0003                  0.0003
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Why do you expect `0.0000083333` to remain unchanged, while `0.000025` should become `0.00002`?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709728/rounding-to-a-specific-number-of-significant-digits-in-oracle

Comment: Your code should work. What datatype is epsilon and what version of Oracle are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be close to do what you want. I would just suggest modifying the regexp so it takes into account numbers on the left side of the dot:

```
TRUNC(EPSILON,LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(EPSILON,'^\d*\.0*')))
```

Comment: sorry i updated the post, 0.0000083333 should become 0.000008.

Comment: @user13442854: yes, this is what I assumed. Does this solution work for your use case?

Comment: How would i modify it to retrieve additional significant digits? say 3 digits in total