# how to get the correct display of numbers when dividing in oracle developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to divide two value in column1 and column2 but I get result like as 5,876544358765677786E-8 in some case. If I try do like ROUND((col1/col2*100),8) || '%' then oracle developer remove first value in some case and I get ,056789543 without first number. How can I fix it than get right result?

I tried put `to_char` instead round

Comment: What are you expecting to be the "right" result. If you have `0.000000058765` (which is the same value, written using scientific notation, as `5.8765e-8`) and want to round it to 8 decimal places then you will get `0.00000006` (which is the same as `6e-8`).

Comment: If you want to round or format the number to a given number of significant figures then this question is a duplicate of [Rounding to a specific number of significant digits in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75766627/1509264).

Answer (score 1):

`5.876544358765677786E-8` is `0.00000005876544358765677786` written using scientific notation. They are the same values just written in a different format.

If you want to specify how the number is formatted then use `TO_CHAR` which will convert it to a formatted string; if you want to leave the value as a number and round it to a set number of decimal places then use `ROUND`:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(value, '99999990.99999999') AS formatted_string,
       ROUND(value, 8) AS rounded_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 5.876544358765677786E-8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5.876544358765677786E0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | FORMATTED_STRING | ROUNDED_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .00000005876544358765677786 | 0.00000006 | .00000006 |
| 5.876544358765677786 | 5.87654436 | 5.87654436 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_QMhmcdU)